# Notepad++ Regular Expression to achieve this result

Tags: notepad++

I would like to have this solution using Notepad++

**BEFORE**:

```
word word word
word word word
word word word
word word word
```

**AFTER**:

```
+word +word +word
+word +word +word
+word +word +word
+word +word +word
```

Comment: A normal search/replace should accomplish this without the need for regular expressions...

Comment: See http://markantoniou.blogspot.ro/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `(\w+)` replace with `+\1`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH GUYS!!. Very helpful.. just a matter of seconds.. Amazing community here.

Answer (score 1):

Search for:

```
(word)
```

Replace for:

```
+\1
```

(But as it was said in the comment, a normal search would easily do that)

But if you are searching by **any** word, then use this:

Search for:

```
([A-Za-z]+)
```

Replace for:

```
+\1
```

Comment: The sample word there could be any word. like for example: my name is

Comment: @user3126697:  you can replace `word` with any given regular expression.  The point is the `(` and `)` which capture the sequence, and the `\1` which expresses the capture in the replacement.

Comment: Yes, the sample word is there now, but if the word has special characters (like latin ones: á é, and so on), this would not match.

Comment: The other answer, search for (\w+) replace with +\1 is better than, due to the special chars.

Comment: Well, \w also accept numbers and special chars! :) check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards

Comment: Thanks to you Lauro Wolff